# Implementing V10 of the OAuth2 specification with Indy

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, indy, indy10

I am attempting an OAuth2 implementation for MailChimp.

In [their API documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/) they state

> Our server implements v10 of the OAuth2 specification, and supports
>   Web Server Flow.

For past OAuth2 implementations I have used these settings:

```
  SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv23];
  --- or ---
  SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
```

Does Indy10 support **Version 10**??

```
 TIdSSLVersion = (sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2);
```

I am getting a "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error when I attempt the OAuth call.  Not sure if this is bad parameters or I am not sending the correct SSL versioning.  They don't provide much documentation/troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indy does not support OAuth at all, let alone v10 of OAuth2.  There are several third-party OAuth implementations available that use Indy, though.

That being said, the communications with the server are just plain HTTPS, which Indy handles just fine.  Assuming you are sending a request to an `https:` url and not an `http:` url, the fact that you see "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" at all means SSL/TLS is working fine, since the request and response are both encrypted.  "Bad Request" simply means your HTTP request parameters were wrong.

Without seeing the actualHTTP messages, I can only guess that maybe the OAuth authentication was malformed in some way.

Comment: Thank you Remy for detailed response.  After further digging I found out a return url was not set properly (had to be the same return url as the first stage of the OAuth authentication).